# Embedded question subject verb inversion

Tags: grammar

I want to ask about embedded questions, which one is right?

- I want to know who is your favorite actor. (subject is who)
- I wanna know who your favorite actor is.
  (Subject is your favorite actor)

Do you think both sentences are OK if the subjects are different?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141067/discussion-on-question-by-sunny-embedded-question-subject-verb-inversion).

Answer (score 2):

> [1] *I want to know* [*who is your favorite actor*].
>
> [2] *I want to know* [*who your favorite actor is*].

Preliminary point: there is no inversion. The subject in [1] is "who" and in [2] "your favorite actor", and they both precede their verb, "is".

They have the same basic meaning:

"*I want to know the answer to the question 'Who is your favorite*
*actor?*'"